# How to find the dominant singularity of the function $\frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}}{2 z}$?

Tags: combinatorics, limits

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599663/finding-the-coefficients-of-the-ogf-of-unary-binary-trees/4604567#4604567):

> Find the dominant singularity of the function $$M(z) = \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}}{2 z}.$$

My idea would be to use Pringsheim's Theorem: From before we already know that $M(z)$ can be represented by the power series $A(z) := \sum_{n \ge 0} a_nz^n$, where
$$a_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k-1},$$

so what we need to compute is the convergence radius $R$ of $A(z)$. For this I suppose that we need the formula

$$ R = \frac{1}{\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert a_n \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}}}.$$

However, I do not see how to evaluate $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert a_n \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the limit is harder to compute directly (not via singularity analysis), so you're doing things in reverse. The singular points are simply the roots of $1-2z-3z^2=0$, which are $z=1/3$ and $z=-1$. Now $R$ is the distance (from the origin) to the closest singularity, thus clearly $R=1/3$.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I do not understand why $1/3$ and $-1$ are the branch points of $M(z)$. When I plug the values in i get $M(-1) = -1$ and $M(1/3) = 1$, so I do not see any ambiguity there.

Comment: @3nondatur: the reason is roughly the same as for why $z=0$ is a branch point of $z^{1/2}$: the function is not analytic around there. That's also why a textbook example $(1-z)^{1/2}$ has the power series which converges on $|z|<1$ "only".