# How to do a singularity analysis on $M(z) := \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}}{2 z}$?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, asymptotics

This question is realted to these [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599663/finding-the-coefficients-of-the-ogf-of-unary-binary-trees/4604567#4604567) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608078/how-to-find-the-dominant-singularity-of-the-function-frac1-z-sqrt1-2/4608184?noredirect=1#comment9711010_4608184) of mine:

> Use singularity analysis on
> $$ M(z) := \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}}{2 z}$$
>
> to show that
>
> $$[z^n]M(z) = 3^n \sqrt{\frac{3}{4 \pi n^3}} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr) \biggr)$$

I understand now that $1/3$ is the dominant singularity of $M$. And from the lecture I know the transfer theorem and the

> **Standard function scale:** Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\le 0}$. Then
> $$[z^n] (1-z)^{-\alpha} = \frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr) \biggr).$$

I can see that the formula for the standard function scale looks pretty similar to what is asked, but I do not see how to apply it here. Could you please give me a hint on how to proceed?

Edit: So far I got, using the binomial expansion of $(1-3z)^{1/2}$, that

$$(1-3z)^{1/2} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{1/2}{k} 3^kz^k$$

and by the standard function scale and the fact that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ this entails

$$[z^n](1-3z)^{1/2} = \frac{3^n}{n^{3/2}\Gamma(1/2)} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\biggr) = 3^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi n^{3}}} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\biggr).$$

We furthermore get

\begin{align}
[z^n]\frac{(1-3z)^{1/2}}{2z} &= \frac{3^{n-1}}{2(n-1)^{3/2}\Gamma(1/2)} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n-1}\biggr)\biggr) \\
&= 3^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi (n-1)^{3}}} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\biggr).
\end{align}

Comment: write $\sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}=\sqrt{(1+z)(1-3z)}$ and use the expansion of $\sqrt{1 -3z}$ at $1/3$ to get the $n^{-3/2}(1+O(1/n))$ asymptotic, scaled by $3^n$ of course while the coefficients follow by plugging in $z=1/3$ and noting that $1/z$ gives you a shift so the $n$th coefficient here is the $n+1$ there etc

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get it. I fail to see what you mean by "expansion of $\sqrt{1-3z}$ at $1/3$". I tried to compute it, but the denomiator of the derivatives is always zero, so this does not work out. On the other hand using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+z}$ at $1/3$ works better (see my edit).

Comment: The binomial expansion gives $(1-3z)^{1/2}=\sum a_n3^nz^n$ where $a_n=c n^{-3/2}(1+O(1/n)$ and then you have to shift and also take care of the extra coefficients

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention that $M(z)$ is the ordinary generating function of [OEIS sequence A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006) "Motzkin numbers" which has many many references and links.

Comment: @Conrad. Thanks for your answer, however, I do not quite understand the part with "taking care of the extra coefficients". What do you mean by "plugging in z = 1/3"? (I wrote down how far I got in an edit.)

Comment: wrote below how to finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment that got too long and explains where you need to change your computations.

First $\alpha=-1/2$ in the formula so you need $|\Gamma(-1/2)|=2\sqrt \pi$ (not forgetting that $M$ has the square root with a minus, canceling the minus of $\Gamma(-1/2)$)

Second, you need to normalize the term $\sqrt {1+z}$ at $1/3$ since you have that in $M(z)$ too, and that is done by using

$$\sqrt {1+z}\sqrt {1-3z }= \biggl(\sqrt {1+z}-\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\biggr)\sqrt{1-3z}+ \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\sqrt {1-3z}$$

and noting that $(\sqrt {1+z}-2/\sqrt 3)=(1-3z)g(z)$ with $g$ analytic at $1/3$ so the term $(\sqrt {1+z}-2/\sqrt 3)\sqrt {1-3z}$ is of lower order and can be incorporated in the error.

Third, when you divide by $z$ you need the coeeficient of $z^{n+1}$ in the binomial expansion of $\sqrt {1-3z}$ to get the (dominant) coefficient of $z^n$ in $M(z)$ so putting it together we get that for $n \ge 1$

$$[z^n](M(z))= \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}[z^{n+1}]\frac{(1-3z)^{1/2}}{2}+ \text{error}$$ where the error above is one (negative) power of $n$ extra coming from the expansion of $(1-3z)^{3/2}$, hence it can be incorporated in the final $O(1/n)$, hence

$$[z^n](M(z)) = \frac{3^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{3 \pi} (n+1)^{3/2}}\biggl(1+O \biggl(\frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)\biggr)$$

But clearly $(n+1)^{-3/2}(1+O(1/(n+1))=n^{-3/2}(1+O(1/n))$ so one finally gets that

$$[z^n]M(z) = 3^n \sqrt{\frac{3}{4 \pi n^3}} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr) \biggr)$$